# Clear for inline elements is not working in the same way as block elements

Tags: html, css

Im floating an image and then I have added another image width `clear:left`. I expected the second image not to be on the right side of the first image, but below since it has `clear:left`.

If I change the second image by a paragraph width `clear:left` too, **the paragraph is shown below the image.**

```html
<img src="http://www.ziiweb.com/images/logo.png" style="float: left">

<img style="clear: left" src="http://www.ziiweb.com/images/logo.png" >
```

Answer (score 0):

add clear:left with float:left;

```
<img src="http://www.ziiweb.com/images/logo.png" style="float: left">

<img style="clear: left;float: left;"src="http://www.ziiweb.com/images/logo.png" >
```